# Best .Net library to edit WMA tags?

Tags: .net, id3, wma

I have found a few libraries to edit MP3 tags (UltraID3Lib is great) but none that will edit tags for WMA files.

Can anyone recommend a .net library for editing WMA tags / metadata ?

Thanks
MATT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TagLib#  http://www.taglibsharp.com

Doh!  How did I miss this?